# Can't configure autoscale on Azure web app

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to set Autoscale on my Azure Web App but can't seems to get it working. **Any idea?**

[image: Set Instance Count to 2 and 4]
[image: Save and Get and Error]
[image: Detail error message]

Comment: Try to do it in the new portal. If that doesn't work I suggest you contact Azure support.

Answer (score 0):

Even if in the old portal, it should work for you. I just tried it on my subscription (old website and new azure web app both were able to scale)
I read elsewhere that sometimes this could be a browser issue. Deleting cookies and cache and the browsing history resolves the issue. let me know if this solves it for you. Or maybe a simple refresh and try again?

Plus it is showing 2 instances in the scale graph, have you been able to scaled it from 1 to 2 previously? as this doesn't get updated unless the scale configuration/change was saved.

Comment: @DavidMakogon i know, that's why i noted "read somewhere else" :) i tried replicating this didn't work for me